# How to edit response from @GetMapping in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class where i have a @ManyToOne relationship. When i create a @GetMapping for that class the response includes all the data from that relationship, and i only want to print the name.
This are my classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Transactions")
public class Transaction implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idTransaction;
    

    private double amount;
    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idSender")
    private User sender;
    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idReceiver")
    private User receiver;
    
    private int likes;
    private List<String> comments;

    private Date date;
    
    public Transaction() {
    }

    public Transaction( double amount, User sender, User receiver, int likes, List<String> comments,
            Date date) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Transaction [idTransaction=" + idTransaction + ", amount=" + amount + ", sender=" + sender
                + ", receiver=" + receiver + ", likes=" + likes + ", comments=" + comments + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Transaction> findTransactions() {
        return tService.findAllTransactions();
    }
```

Service:

```
    @Override
    public List<Transaction> findAllTransactions() {
        return tRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Integer> {

    
}
```

I´ve tried using:

`@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

But it thows this error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.BankSolera.Banking.Types.Transaction["sender"]->com.BankSolera.Banking.Types.User$HibernateProxy$BnB9XIDU["hibernateLazyInitializer"]) t`

Comment: Have you tried with `@JsonIgnore` annotation?

Comment: Yes, I´ve tried that but it hides everything and i want to try to display the names of the sender and the receiver

Comment: Add `@JsonIgnore` to the fields you want to hide, not to the entire class

Comment: But when i print the User i want all the fields to show up

Comment: @Charbasket,  have you tried disabling SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS as suggested in the exception message?

Comment: We should never expose entity classes via Api so I will  suggest to create DTO on top of entity class and do required mapping.

Comment: Using a DTO worked, thanks for all the comments